# change data grid view row colour depend upon the value

Tags: vb.net

I have a DataGridView like this:
[image]

I am binding the DataGridView like this:

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("DashBordFetch", con.connect)  
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure   
cmd.Parameters.Add("@locid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = locid
da.SelectCommand = cmd
da.Fill(ds)
DGVDashBoard.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
```

I want to my DataGridView to have a red row color when the Value is 1. How can I do that? I am working in VB.NET.

I have tried the code in one of the answers provided, it looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
 Private Sub DGVDashBoard_CellFormatting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles DGVDashBoard.CellFormatting
            Dim drv As DataRowView
            If e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
                ' Add Your condition here ignore following
                If e.RowIndex <= ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1 Then
                    drv = ds.Tables(0).DefaultView.Item(e.RowIndex)
                    Dim c As Color
                    If drv.Item("Value").ToString = "1" Then
                        c = Color.Red                        
                    End If
                    e.CellStyle.BackColor = c
                End If
            End If
        End Sub
```

Let me know if this doesn't work.

Comment: value i return as integer in my datagrid view,if the value is 1 then only i want show particular row in red color

Comment: while executing your code getting error like this:Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: where i have to specify my gridview name?

Comment: sir,,that is working fine..but my data grid view data not showing clearly.i attached image of that

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub CustomersGridView_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)

    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

      If(your condition)
         e.Row.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Red 
      End If

    End If

  End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Senthilkumar
I was looking for something that would allow me to color the background of a row if the Text equals Closed. Here is my final solution I just had to add the ToString after value. The DataGridviewTextBoxColumn16 name is from the datagridview properties. Click the Arrow at the top right of DataGridView, edit columns and find the name value. Hope that helps someone.

```
For Each rw As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        If rw.Cells("DataGridViewTextBoxColumn16").Value.ToString = "Closed" Then
            rw.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red
        Else
            rw.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 1):

'Use this code for change color of specific row in cellformatting event of 'datagridview

```
        For Each drview As DataGridViewRow In dgrawPRoducts.Rows
            If drview.Cells.Count >= 14 Then
                If Not IsNothing(drview.Cells(14).Value) Then
                    If drview.Cells(14).Value.ToString.Trim = "N" Then
                        For i As Integer = 0 To drview.Cells.Count - 1
                            drview.Cells(i).Style.ForeColor = Color.Red
                           drview.Cells(i).Style.BackColor= Color.Gray
                        Next

                    End If
                End If
            End If

        Next
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    For Each rw As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows 
    If rw.Cells("slno").Value =1 Then 
    rw.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red
    Else 
    rw.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green
    End If 
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

here's my code:

```
For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
    row.BackColor = Drawing.Color.White
Next row
```

Comment: I guess you need to change the code to `row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White`

Comment: I am surprised by seeing your comment after 2 years :)